# Access type fields in data constructor haskell

Tags: haskell, types, syntax, output

I have a question how do I access certain types in a data constructor. Lets say I got this code sample

```
data Object = Object Type1 Type2 Type3 Type4
  deriving(Eq,Show)
type Type1 = Float
type Type2 = Bool
type Type3 = Int
type Type4 = String
```

and I define a function called

```
construct = Object 5.6 True 10 "World"
```

How can I print certain types from construct for example I want to print "World" from construct how can I get that information.

```
Type4 construct
```

does not work

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Types start with uppercase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## With *pattern matching*

We can construct a function that uses pattern matching:

```
objectType1 :: Object -> Type1
objectType1 (Object x _ _ _) = x
```

## With *record syntax*

We can also define a data type with *record syntax*:

```
data Object = Object {objectType1 :: Type1,
                      objectType2 :: Type2,
                      objectType3 :: Type3,
                      objectType4 :: Type4} deriving(Eq, Show)
```

Haskell will then automatically construct getters, so then you have implictly constructed such `objectType1` function.

We can also use such record syntax as a "*setter*", for example:

```
setObjectType1 :: Type1 -> Object -> Object
setObjectType1 t o = o { objectType1 = t}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, the line

```
Object t1 t2 t3 t4 = construct
```

seems to unpack the four fields. I'm new to Haskell, so I don't know if that is a kind of documented behavior or recommended method (sort of pattern matching?).